# How can I convert char to symbol in common lisp?

Tags: list, lisp, common-lisp

Total lisp beginner here.

I'm wondering how to convert a character to symbol. Simply what I want is convert `#\a` to `a`

Here what I have done so far:

```
(defun convert(char)
(if(eq char #\a)
    (setq char 'a))
    char)
```

This one is works actually but I don't want to add 26 conditions(letters in alphabet) and make a long-dumb code.

Also I'm wondering is there any functions in common lisp that converts character list to symbol list like: `(#\h #\e #\l #\l #\o)` to `(h e l l o)` ? I have found `intern` and `make-symbol` related to that but they require string as parameter.

Comment: The `setq` assignment is pointless; your function returns `'a` without accessing that variable again, which goes out of scope.  Also `eq` is not officially suitable for testing character equality. Use [`eql`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_eql.htm). See how the doc talks about support for character equality testing? And that for [`eq`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_eq.htm) says *An implementation is permitted to make ``copies'' of characters and numbers at any time. *

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
CL-USER 230 > (intern (string #\Q))
Q
NIL

CL-USER 231 > (intern (string #\q))
\q
NIL
```

Btw., your code has a bunch of improvements necessary:

```
(defun convert(char)   ; 
(if(eq char #\a)       ; use EQL instead of EQ for characters
                       ; indentation is wrong
    (setq char 'a))    ; indentation is wrong
    char)              ; indentation is wrong
```

Better write it as:

```
(defun convert (char)
  (if (eql char #\a)
      'a
      char))
```

or

```
(defun convert (char)
  (case char
    (#\a 'a)
    (#\b 'b)
    (otherwise char)))
```

As mentioned above, the 'real' solution is:

```
(defun convert (char)
  (intern (string char)))
```

Comment: in your enviroment you get "\" before q and I get "|" symbols in mine. May I ask what are these ? I got `|q|` for `(intern (string #\q))`

Comment: they are escape characters to ensure that the symbol may keep the lowercase characters in the symbol name.

Comment: @sushibossftw: Note that `|a|` is the same symbol as `\a`: ` (eq '|a| '\a)` is true.  Backslash escapes the next character while `|...|` escapes all the characters between the bars.   I think the implementation is at liberty to use either in the printer.  They're needed because (with default reader settings) `(symbol-name 'a)` is `"A"`.

Answer (score 2):

```
(defun converter (c)
  (if (characterp c)
      (make-symbol (string c))))
```

You could use make-symbol and convert the symbol to a string.

```
(setq my-sym (converter #\a))
```

Comment: Sure, this one is a fine solution also.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question after a while:

*Also I'm wondering is there any functions in common lisp that converts character list to symbol list like: (#\h #\e #\l #\l #\o) to (h e l l o) ?*

I can convert single character to symbol with this convert function:

```
(defun convert (c)
    (if (characterp c)
        (intern (string c))))
```

Since one of main ideas of LISP is "processing a list" I can use one of map functions to apply one operation to every single element of the list.

```
(mapcar #'convert '(#\h #\e #\l #\l #\o))
```

Here `mapcar` function will result the list of symbols:

```
(|h| |e| |l| |l| |o|)
```